# conversationToolkitAPI events not available in pop-up

Tags: aura, chat, service

Im using aura component that leverage conversationToolkitAPI to listen to messages in service chat and it works well when component is added to page or utility bar. But when component is in utility bar and user decides to use it in pop-up it doesnt receive newMessage event. Omni component is added to utility, from which i open chat in service page. Custom Component has access="global", im thinking if this event should be accessible in popup at all, and if there is any good way to integrate the chat with this custom component in pop-up other than using Chat REST API which I'm trying to avoid